# Wrapping nested ASStackLayoutSpec with AsyncDisplayKit

Tags: ios, swift, asyncdisplaykit

Using nested `ASStackLayoutSpec` with AsyncDisplayKit I am trying to achieve this

[image]

So I am creating a vertical `ASStackLayoutSpec` with avatar and another horizontal `ASStackLayoutSpec` with the user name and timestamp and text

```
override func layoutSpecThatFits(_ constrainedSize: ASSizeRange) -> ASLayoutSpec {
    // HEADER with username and timestamp
    let spacer = ASLayoutSpec()
    spacer.style.flexGrow = 1
    let headerStackSpec = ASStackLayoutSpec.horizontal()
    headerStackSpec.spacing = 2
    headerStackSpec.alignItems = .baselineFirst
    headerStackSpec.children = [userNode, spacer, timestampNode]

    // CONTENT - HEADER and text
    let contentStackSpec = ASStackLayoutSpec.vertical()
    contentStackSpec.spacing = 2
    contentStackSpec.children = [headerStackSpec, messageNode]

    // MAIN - avatar and CONTENT
    let mainStackSpec = ASStackLayoutSpec.horizontal()
    mainStackSpec.spacing = 9
    mainStackSpec.children = [avatarNode, contentStackSpec]

    return ASInsetLayoutSpec(insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 10, bottom: 2, right: 10), child: mainStackSpec)
}
```

But the result is not what I expected

[image]

It looks like the text goes to infinity, not properly wraping. The timestamp is also probably somewhere far away on the right out of bounds.

I tried different combinations of `.alignItems` and `.justifyContent` but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Try setting the style.width for ASLayoutElements like ASStackLayoutSpec etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these properties:

```
contentStackSpec.style.flexShrink = 1
messageNode.style.flexShrink = 1
contentStackSpec.children = [headerStackSpec, messageNode]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `width` of you message node in the method `layoutSpecThatFits`:

```
let messageWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds - (leftSpacing + rightSpacing)
message.style.width = ASDimension(unit: .points, value: messageWidth)
```